# How to detect if image is being displayed as negative (inverted)?

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

Is it possible to detect if an image is being displayed as a "Negative Image" in C#? In other words the colors are inverted?

Comment: I think this is a really hard problem, no matter the language. You'd probably need to have a set of negative image to "train" your algorithm to find them, but even then, you could only identify them to a certain degree of certainty and you'd probably always get false results (negatives being flagged and non-negative and vice versa).

Comment: Try to detect whether or not the picture of a checkerboard is inverted, for example, or a 70% gray card. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the original image to compare (and then what you are trying to do is detecting if an image is the negative of another one), then you can only try to guess that it is some kind of negative image, but you cannot be 100% sure about it.
The negative image is simply the image where each pixel colour is:
Red = 255 - originalRed
Green = 255 - originalGreen
Blue = 255 - originalBlue

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the colour of any particular pixel should be you can test that to see if it matches or is inverted.

Other than that I can't think of a foolproof way that would work for any image. You could look at colour distributions but that will depend on the image.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do some statistical analysis on the properties of inverted and non-inverted images to get some criteria to check. For example, perhaps there are colors that are uncommon in normal images but common in inverted ones. Maybe the center of a normal image is usually brighter than the edges, or the top is brighter than the bottom.

No method is going to be 100% accurate, as any image is ultimately just as valid as any other.